# Calculating the velocity of fluid in a pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

How can I calculate the steady state velocity of air inside a long pipe just knowing the pressure at the inlet and outlet?

Comment: You know Bernoulli's principle?

Comment: There are standard software packages that can calculate flow rate for compressible flow.  Do you have access to one of those packages?

Comment: @DavidWhite I was hopping to find a method to compute it by hand. I can download OpenFoam, but that's a learning cuerve I dont want to deal with right now

Comment: @user3408085, the calculation is "trial and error" for compressible flow rates, and is related to Reynold's number, pipe roughness, fluid velocity, etc.  If you don't need high accuracy (e.g., +/- 20%), the Bernoulli equation may work.  How accurate does your estimation have to be?

Comment: https://www.pipeflowcalculations.com/pipe-valve-fitting-flow/compressible-gas-flow.php#isothermal-compressible-flow-in-pipe

Comment: Thanks @ChesterMiller , that was what I was looking for. Do you want to put it as an answer? Or should I do it for you?

Comment: Yeah.  I’ll do it when i’m Back at my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The velocity is not constant, and varies along the length of the pipe in inverse proportion to the density change. The mass flow rate is constant, and, for essentially constant temperature, so is the Reynolds number. So, for a given mass flow rate, you can calculate the pressure gradient using the Darcy Weisbach correlation in conjunction with the ideal gas law. You can then integrate to get the total pressure change and see if it matches the desired pressure change. If not, you iterate on the assumed mass flow rate.  When you solve the problem the way I indicated, because of the coupling to the ideal gas law, your integration involves the pressure squared, rather than the pressure. This is a standard calculation used for natural gas pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a laminar flow you can use Hagen-Poiseulle law:
$$Q=\frac{\pi R^4}{8\mu}\frac{\Delta p}{L}$$ where $Q$ denotes the volumetric flow rate, $R$ the radius of the pipe, $\mu$ the dynamic viscosity, $\Delta p$ the pressure difference and $L$ the length of the pipe. But $$Q=v\cdot A = v\cdot \pi R^2$$ where $v$ is the averaged velocity and $A$ the cross-sectional area of the pipe. By combining these two equations you will get the velocity as
$$v = \frac{R^2}{8\mu}\frac{p_i-p_o}{L} .$$

Comment: EuklidAlexandria, the version of the continuity equation that you used applies only to incompressible flow.  Air is compressible, so as the pressure drops, the air density goes down.  Due to this, the calculation of air flow is a bit more complicated, and the changing density, with the changing air velocity, must be accounted for in the calculation of flow.

Comment: @DavidWhite Yes, you are right. I thought you can assume the density staying more or less constant in a rough approximation.